# Missing method getSession while migrating facebook php sdk from v4 to v5

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

While trying to migrate the Faceboook PHP SDk from v4 to v5, I get the error:

```
An uncaught Exception was encountered

Type: Error

Message: Call to undefined method Facebook\Helpers\FacebookPageTabHelper::getSession()
```

The `getSession()` method is missing in v5.

How to replace the getSession() method in v5 ?

Using v4, I had to set the APP_ID and APP_SECRET like:

```
include_once('assets/facebook/autoload.php');
FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication(FACEBOOK_APP_ID, FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET);
```

and then I was just initialising the `FacebookPageTabHelper` class like this:

```
$helper = new FacebookPageTabHelper();
```

and then I had the code:

```
$helper = $fb->getPageTabHelper();
        if ($helper->getPageId()) {
            $data['page'] = [
                'id' => $helper->getPageId(),
                'admin' => $helper->isAdmin(),
                'liked' => false
            ];
        }

/* IF PAGE SESSION AUTO LOGIN USER */
        if ($helper->getSession()) {
            $session = $helper->getSession();
        }
```

In v5, I am doing like this:

```
require_once('assets/facebook/facebook-php-sdk-v-5/autoload.php');
    $fb = new Facebook\Facebook(
            [
        'app_id' => FACEBOOK_APP_ID,
        'app_secret' => FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET,
        'default_graph_version' => 'v2.8',
            ]
    );

$helper = $fb->getPageTabHelper();
        if ($helper->getPageId()) {
            $data['page'] = [
                'id' => $helper->getPageId(),
                'admin' => $helper->isAdmin(),
                'liked' => false
            ];
        }

* IF PAGE SESSION AUTO LOGIN USER */
        if ($helper->getSession()) {
            $session = $helper->getSession();
        }
```

Comment: The whole `FacebookSession` class was removed. Go check the documentation, it has plenty of examples for basic requests etc.

Comment: Any documentation besides sammyk ?